# Replace sub select counts with a more efficient method

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I appear to be having a little spazzy moment today and can't seem to come up with a better way of doing sub select counts on a table.

Basically what I need to do is for each distinct supplier I then need 2 counts (from the same table) one for the total records assigned to that supplier and one for disputed records for that supplier.  At the moment I have the query below which is technically correct but slow as hell on a table with 1 mill + records.  I'm sure there's a better way of doing it but I can't for the life of me work it out this morning.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT tblsuppliers.SupplierName, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblmovements a WHERE m.Supplier=a.Supplier AND a.TicketStatus IN(0,1) AND a.DateRequired>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND a.DateRequired<='2013-11-30 23:59:59') as 'Total Tickets',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblmovements b WHERE m.Supplier=b.Supplier AND b.TicketStatus IN(0,1) AND b.DateRequired>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND b.DateRequired<='2013-11-30 23:59:59' AND (b.SuppIsDisputed=1 OR b.SuppDisputeClearedBy>0)) as 'Total Disputed'
FROM tblmovements m 
INNER JOIN tblsuppliers ON m.Supplier=tblsuppliers.ID 
ORDER BY tblsuppliers.SupplierName ASC
```

The joined table is just to give me an supplier name as opposed to the supplier ID which is stored in the movements table.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answers below should provide performance benefits but if you're still struggling, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET - and don't give us that guff about being unable to provide data. ;-)

Comment: First I would ensure that you have the proper indexes used for your query. If that is the case and speed is still unsatisfactory I would try `exporting` the counts into `materialized views`, one for the first count and one for the other, that way the counting is done while inserting/building the view - and selecting it will be much faster

Comment: Trying to avoid views since this is a one off query rather than a regular occurance i'm just trying to get some stats for one of the directors :)  Index's are on all columns being used for the joins etc so i'm fairly confident its just down to the fact i'm being dumb and using sub select counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.SupplierName, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.TicketStatus IN(0,1) AND m.DateRequired>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND 
                     m.DateRequired<='2013-11-30 23:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END)  AS 'Total Tickets', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.TicketStatus IN(0,1) AND m.DateRequired>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND 
                     m.DateRequired<='2013-11-30 23:59:59' AND 
                    (m.SuppIsDisputed=1 OR m.SuppDisputeClearedBy>0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) AS 'Total Disputed'
FROM tblmovements m 
INNER JOIN tblsuppliers s ON m.Supplier=s.ID 
GROUP BY s.ID 
ORDER BY s.SupplierName ASC
```

Comment: Both solutions work so I've +1'd thanks for the help knew I was being retarded somewhere

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
tblsuppliers.SupplierName, 
SUM(IF(TicketStatus IN(0,1) AND DateRequired>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND DateRequired<='2013-11-30 23:59:59', 1, 0)) as 'Total Tickets',
SUM(IF(TicketStatus IN(0,1) AND DateRequired>='2013-09-01 00:00:00' AND DateRequired<='2013-11-30 23:59:59' AND (SuppIsDisputed=1 OR SuppDisputeClearedBy>0), 1, 0)) as 'Total Disputed'
FROM tblmovements m 
INNER JOIN tblsuppliers ON m.Supplier=tblsuppliers.ID 
GROUP BY tblsuppliers.SupplierName
```

Comment: Both solutions work so I've +1'd both but Saharsh has less score overall than you so I've given him the accept thanks for the help knew I was being retarded somewhere